# Clojure boolean confusion when entered via a string

Tags: vector, clojure, boolean, sequence, prompt

What am I missing here?...

While this works perfectly fine:

```
(def env [true true true false])
=> #'clojquery.core/env
(boolean (first (drop 3 env)))
=> false
```

I cannot get the same behavior if I convert a string from read-line for the forth value:

```
(def env (do
           (println "Enter boolean: ")
           (let [in (read-line)]
             (concat [true true true] (map symbol (re-seq #"\w+" in))))))

Enter boolean: 
false
=> #'clojquery.core/env
(vec env)
=> [true true true false]
(first (drop 3 (vec env)))
=> false
(boolean (first (drop 3 env)))
=> true
(if (first (drop 3 (vec env))) "TRUE" "FALSE")
=> "TRUE"
```

Isn't that odd?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9):

In Clojure, `false` and `nil` are falsey and everything else is truthy.

You're creating a symbol from the input string. You can create a symbol from any string. A symbol is not `false` or `nil` so all symbols are truthy.

```
(boolean? (symbol "false")) ;;=> false -- it isn't a Boolean
(symbol? (symbol "false")) ;;=> true -- it's a Symbol
(boolean? false) ;;=> true -- false is a Boolean
(symbol? false) ;;=> false -- false isn't a Symbol
```

So `true` and `false` are not symbols in Clojure -- they are values.

If you're using Clojure 1.11, you can call `parse-boolean` on your input string to produce `true` or `false` *values*. However, that will throw an exception if you enter something that cannot be parsed as a Boolean value so it depends what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I also realized I could leave it as a string and use the Java method Boolean.ValueOf(String S). And indeed (boolean (Boolean/valueOf "false")) works as intended.